# UML help C# Design Principles

Tags: c#, oop, uml, design-principles

Could anyone please point out the meaning of the graph below:

[image]

1. What is the relationship between PolicyLayer and PolicyServiceInterface
2. What is the relationship between PolicyServiceInterface and MachanismLayer.

C# code would be also appreciated!

Please note that the UML is from Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#
By Martin C. Robert, Martin Micah 2006.

**Added on 15 2011/6/2**

Do the following have the same meaning:
1) A solid line with a triangle at one end
2) A dashed line with a triangle at one end

**Added on 2011/6/3  1st**

What is the difference between:
1) A solid line with an arrow at one end
2) A dashed line with an arrow at one end

Example in thie sample and PersistentObject and ThirdPartyPersistentSet in the link below:

[UML help C# Design Principles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208308/uml-help-c-design-principles/6208441)

**Added on 2011/6/3 2nd**

Can the relationship between PolicyLayer and PolicyServiceInterface as below:

```
public class PolicyLayer

{
    private PolicyServiceInterface policyServiceInterface = new PolicyServiceInterfaceImplementation();
}

class PolicyServiceInterfaceImplementation:PolicyServiceInterface {}
```

Regarding

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208308/uml-help-c-design-principles

Answer (score 7):

> 1) What is the relationship between PolicyLayer and PolicyServiceInterface

The -----> is [`Association`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter?origURL=api/redirect/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp) ("knows a")

[image: Association]
<sub>(source: [sedris.org](http://www.sedris.org/drawings/uml_8.gif))</sub>

C# code:

```
public interface PolicyServiceInterface { }

public class PolicyLayer
{
    private IPolicyServiceInterface _policyServiceInterface;
    // Constructor Assocation
    public PolicyLayer(IPolicyServiceInterface policyServiceInterface)
    {
        _policyServiceInterface = policyServiceInterface;
    }
}
```

> 2) What is the relationship between PolicyServiceInterface and MachanismLayer.

The - - -|> is [`Realization`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter?origURL=api/redirect/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp) ("implements")

[image: Realization]

C# Code:

```
public interface PolicyServiceInterface { }

public class MachanismLayer : PolicyServiceInterface
```

> 3) Do the following have the same meaning: 1) A solid line with a triangle at one end 2) A dashed line with a triangle at one end?

No they have different meanings:

The -----|> is [`Generalization`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter?origURL=api/redirect/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp) ("inherits")

[image: Generalization]

C# Code:

```
public class PolicyServiceInterface { } // could also be abstract

public class MachanismLayer : PolicyServiceInterface
```

> What is the difference between: 1) A solid line with an arrow at one end 2) A dashed line with an arrow at one end

The - - -> is [`Dependency`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter?origURL=api/redirect/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp) ("uses a") There are various forms of dependency including local variables, parameter values, static function calls or return values.

[image: Dependency]

C# Code:

```
// Here Foo is dependent on Baz
// That is Foo - - -> Baz
public class Foo {
   public int DoSomething() { // A form of local variable dependency
       Baz x = new Baz();
       return x.GetInt();
   } 
}
```

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6208308/uml-help-c-sharp-design-principles/6231433#6231433) for Composition and Aggregation.

Comment: @SwDevMan81 thank you for your advice. Do the following have the same meaning: 
1) A solid line with a triangle at one end 
2) A dashed line with a triangle at one end

Comment: @SwDevMan81, Thank you for your advice. I noticed that the C# for realization is different from what I thought.  

What is the difference between: 

1) A solid line with an arrow at one end 2) A dashed line with an arrow at one end

In C#, there is a difference in the way that a method parameter is or is not used.

In C#, there is a difference in the way that a method parameter is used.

Comment: @Pingpong - I've updated my answer to address your latest question

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Thank you for your advice again. Please review my update on 2011/6/3  1st and 2nd.

Comment: @Pingpong - I already address 1st, and for 2nd, no, that is composition (The diamond symbol)

Answer (score 2):

PolicyLayer uses Policy service interface(probabily it holds a reference)
MachanismLayer implements PolicyServiceInterface

```
 public interface IPolicyServiceInterface
    {
        void DoSomething();
    }

    public class MachanismLayer : IPolicyServiceInterface
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MachanismLayer Do Something");
        }
    }

    public class PolicyLayer
    {
        private IPolicyServiceInterface _policyServiceInterface;
        public PolicyLayer(IPolicyServiceInterface policyServiceInterface)
        {
            _policyServiceInterface = policyServiceInterface;
        }

        public void DoSomethig()
        {
            _policyServiceInterface.DoSomething();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] agrs)
        {
           MachanismLayer machanismLayer=new MachanismLayer();
           PolicyLayer policyLayer = new PolicyLayer(machanismLayer);
           policyLayer.DoSomethig();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso, thanks for your advice! Why do both A solid line and a dashed line with a triangle at one end has the same meaning?

Comment: the difference is between a normal arrow and the one with the triangle at the end. the first one mean it uses the second of it type of:
http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/classDiagram.htm

Comment: Sorry, I might not make my self clear. I meant the difference between 1)a solid line with a triangle at the end. 2) a dashed line with the same triangle at the end.

Comment: In the class diagram you should only use solid line: the dashed doens't mean anything in this diagram. In the Sequence Diagram the dashed line is used to show an Async message and the solid line for a Sync one but again in this case all the line should be solid

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso thank you for your advice. But i think it does have difference. solid line with triangle: implement in c#, whereas, dashed line with triangle: inherit.

Comment: UML notation is not related to any language. Dashed line is not documented for class diagram